Is there a limit to telegram getUpdates()?
I have been using https://api.telegram.org/bot${TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}/getUpdates in my code for a few days and when randomly testing today i found many previous entries were missing which were there previously. So, is there any limit to how many results it can show after removing them and showing new ones and if yes how do i get all entries?
i tried using https://api.telegram.org/bot${TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}/getUpdates. I expected it to give all entries but displayed only a few.
i am only able to see message_id = 33,34 and the new ones i add, what about the other one's?

"what about the other one's?" - are those older than 24 hours already?

From the docs "Incoming updates are stored on the server until the bot receives them ..., but they will not be kept longer than 24 hours."

So I won't see 24 hours old updates on /getUpdates?

There are a couple of things you need to be aware of when doing /getUpdates.

The getUpdates call will only return at most 100 updates on a single call. You can specify the limit parameter to adjust this (1-100 is valid)

No updates will be stored longer than 24 hours in the Telegram Bot API server. Hence, you will not be able to retrieve them after 24 hours.


And finally, there's an offset parameter to getUpdates. This will be considered as the update_id of the first update to be returned. By default, updates starting with the earliest unconfirmed update are returned. An update is considered confirmed as soon as getUpdates is called with an offset higher than its update_id.

So, TL;DR: Yes, there are two type of limits. One, number of update returned will not exceed 100. Second, updates arrived earlier than 24 hours will be forgotten.
